# Select last item that doesnt contain specific class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of items, and I would like to find the last item in the list, but the item cannot have specific class. How to write code, so that it checks for class name also.

```
$('ul li:last')
$('ul li:not(.special)')
```

Comment: `$('ul li:not(.special)').last()`

Comment: `$('ul li:not(.special):last')`, does this work?

Comment: @Matjaž Jurečič i think you can't achieve by CSS because it's having two different scenarios need to check i have already asked this kind of que around a week ago but yet not found that answer though i tried to achieve but still could not here css has limtized here **ul li:not([class ='special']){
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}** try this you need a further one step from what i have achieved

Comment: @Matjaž Jurečič i will eagerly love to get the answer in only css

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use jQuery to select the last item it found in the list. So combine what you have with `last()` and you are golden:

```js
// Reference: $("ul li:not('.y')").last().text()
document.write('The last non `y` class contains the text: ' + $("ul li:not('.y')").last().text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="t">Not me.</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
  <li class="t">Not me.</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
  <li class="t">Not me.</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
  <li class="t">This one please!</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
</ul>
```

Heres the docs: https://api.jquery.com/last/

#### Update

You can, of course, just use the CSS selectors nested as well like @RejithRKrishnan said in the comments.

```js
// Reference: $("ul li:not('.y')").last().text()
document.write('The last non `y` class contains the text: ' + $("ul li:not('.y'):last").text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="t">Not me.</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
  <li class="t">Not me.</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
  <li class="t">Not me.</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
  <li class="t">This one please!</li>
  <li class="y">Not me.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$("ul li:not('.y'):last").text()` this one will work right?

Comment: Probably, I honestly don't use the CSS style selectors too often in jQuery so I assume it will. It's probably even a tad faster as its not using memory to store elements that we discard with the `last()` function. I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

this might help. At the ele will contain the last element without that class.

```
 var ele;
  $('ul li').each(function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass("yourclass"))
      {
           ele = this;
      }
  });
```

Comment: This will select the first one without the class, not the last one, and even this could be much simpeler just using `$('ul li.not(.class)').first()` EDIT: ** scratch that** it will select the last one, but just in a much more complex way. It would be simpeler to use `$('ul li.not(.class)')[$('ul li.not(.class)').length-1]` and even that is a bit cumbersome...

Comment: It will select the last one at the end of the loop.... But you are right its much more complex and can be don by jquery selectors.